# change the types of superclass

Tags: python, inheritance

I dont understand how changed type from list to dict on constructor in main class if i got to subclass another type - dict.

What is magic is this?

```
class Adder:
def __init__(self, data = [ ]):
    self.data = data
def __add__(self, other):
    return "Not Implemented"



class DictAdder(Adder):
    def __add__(self, y):
        z = {}
        for k in self.data.keys(): z[k] = self.data[k]
        for k in y.keys(): z[k] = y[k]
        return z




y = DictAdder({1:'a', 2:'b'})
l = y + { 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
print(l)
```

and answer:

```
 {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

Pycharm show what self.data.keys() dont have attribute keys() and this must be  try, because data is a list, but this is work

Comment: Variables don't have types in Python. A variable can be used to point to any type of object: `x = 1; x = []; x = 'foo'`.

Comment: Also [don't use a mutable default argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument), otherwise you might end up posting another question in a while. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`data` *defaults* to a list, but Python isn't a statically typed language so it doesn't have to be. `data` is just a name. Just because we have this:

```
class Adder:
    def __init__(self, data = [ ]):
        self.data = data
```

Doesn't limit our usage. I can still do:

```
i = Adder(4)
s = Adder('hello')
d = Adder({1: 2})
o = Adder(SomeOtherType())
```

As long as whatever uses `Adder.data` uses it correctly for the type it happens to be. Since in this case, `DictAdder` interprets `data` as a `dict`, and it is, that works fine. Of course, if you tried to use a `DictAdder` constructed with a non-`dict`, you would get an error.

Comment: yes, i have error if get list or another type to DictAdder. But, this is good solution as i write? Or is there another solution?